# Why load_half is defined in bpf_helpers but it doesn't appear in filter.c?

Tags: c, header, prototype, ebpf

If I understood "well" within `tools/testing/selftests/bpf/bpf_helpers.h`  bpf heleprs prototypes are defined.

If I want to now which helpers are usable with a specific program type I need to search within the results of `'func_proto(enum bpf_func_id func_id' kernel/ net/ drivers/`

For example to check the helpers which a socket filter program can call I can read the following definition

```
static const struct bpf_func_proto *
sock_filter_func_proto(enum bpf_func_id func_id, const struct bpf_prog *prog)
{
        switch (func_id) {
        /* inet and inet6 sockets are created in a process
         * context so there is always a valid uid/gid
         */
        case BPF_FUNC_get_current_uid_gid:
                return &bpf_get_current_uid_gid_proto;
        case BPF_FUNC_get_local_storage:
                return &bpf_get_local_storage_proto;
        default:
                return bpf_base_func_proto(func_id);
        }
}
```

**QUESTIONS:**

1)I can't see `load_half`, but still I can call it from my socket filter program. Why? 2) which is the difference between `socket_filter` and `sk_filter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `load_half()` is not a BPF helper. The file `bpf_helpers.h` that you mentioned does declare the prototypes for the BPF helper functions, but it also contains other useful definitions such as the `SEC()` or the `bpf_printk()` macros. In particular, it declares `load_half()` with the following comment:

   ```
   /* llvm builtin functions that eBPF C program may use to
    * emit BPF_LD_ABS and BPF_LD_IND instructions
    */
   [...]
   unsigned long long load_half(void *skb,
                                unsigned long long off) asm("llvm.bpf.load.half");
   ```

   As you can read, `load_half()` is an LLVM builtin, an assembly primitive supported by clang/LLVM which is wrapped as `load_half()` for convenience. And because it is not a BPF helper, you will not see it when grepping for its prototype in the kernel.
2. The prefix `sk_filter` is used for eBPF filters attached to sockets, in a similar fashion as what one can do with the legacy cBPF, to filter incoming packets. Although it may be confusing, you can see that `sock_filter_is_valid_access` in kernel file `net/core/filter.c` is used for `cg_sock_verifier_ops`, which is associated in `include/uapi/linux/bpf.h` to program type `BPF_PROG_TYPE_CGROUP_SOCK_ADDR`. So it refers to programs being used in cgroups to [help (containerised) applications to bind and connect](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=7828f20e3779e4e85e55371e0e43f5006a15fb41) their sockets correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. So  sock_filter for cgroup sock and sk_filter for normal socket.